# Remote Desktop Licensing, RemoteAPP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I am going to use RemoteAPP to publish a few administration tools but I ran into a problem with Remote Desktop Licensing which made me confused.
Currently I am stuck at a windows saying that it want to connect to Microsoft Clearinghouse.

- What is Microsoft Clearinghouse?
- Is remote desktop licenses free?
- Do I need to have remote desktop licenses for what I want to do?

My current set up is Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (activated with Windows license).

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RemoteApp and full Remote Desktop Services will require RDS CAL's. However, as with all licensing questions, please see your local software reseller for full details.